# How to merge two projects of two saperate android studio version

Tags: android-studio, merge

Hello i made a app that uses ar core in a old version of android studio and I made the other parts of the app in latest version of android studio as ar core is no more supporded in the latest version of android studio

does anyone knows how to merge the both android studio projects?